# Matlab: Create a matrix from data in a txt file that contains coordinates

Tags: matlab, matrix

[the txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tui1.png)
I need help building the second matrix in the question:

Read the content of the file topographicMap.txt using textscan. Each line in the file contains the following values, separated by a tab: 
 A Y coordinate (an integer value between 1 and 32) 
 An X coordinate (an integer value between 1 and 32) 
The height in the specified coordinate (a floating number) 
 A string – ‘Treasure’ if there is a treasure hidden in the specific location and ‘Normal’ otherwise. (The file contains 3 treasures in total.)

Loop over the contents of map_data and build:

**2) A 3x2 matrix named treasures containing the coordinates of the 3 hidden treasures. The first column should contain the Y coordinates and the second column should contain the X coordinates.**

Comment: The code I wrote runs as I expected. I am facing problems on the second part of the question, creating a 3x2 matrix with the coordinates of the 3 treasures.

Comment: Please [edit] your question in the form of a [mre] and include text as text; not image

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your 3rd column is a serialized full 32x32 matrix, you can just use a reshape to get the entire array

```
map_matrix=reshape(map_data{3},32,32);
```

to get the treasure data points, you shall search 'Treasure' in your last column `map_data{4}` use `ismember`, if you are able to get 6 numbers, then you can also reshape it to 3x2,something like

```
idx=find(ismember(map_data{4},'Treasure'));
if(length(idx)==6)
   treat_matrix=reshape(map_data{3}(idx),3,2);
end
```

Comment: The second matrix needs to be a 3x2 matrix, where the first column contains the Y coordinate and the second one contains the X coordinate of the Treasures .The idx in the code you wrote gave me the 3 heights of the treasures.